# Configuring Scala compiler in IntelliJ 10.5?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get Scala working correctly in IntelliJ 10.5.1. I installed the plugin from the "available plugins" settings and then tried starting a new Java project, selecting "scala" under available technologies. But when I try running it, Scala says I haven't defined a scala compiler in the scala facet. So I went there, but I don't see any way of setting up the compiler. Also, my .iml file in my project looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
      <component name="FacetManager">
        <facet type="scala" name="Scala">
          <configuration>
            <option name="compilerLibraryLevel" value="Global" />
            <option name="pluginPaths">
              <array>
                <option value="$USER_HOME$/SDKs/scala/src/scala-compiler-src.jar" />
              </array>
            </option>
          </configuration>
        </facet>
      </component>
      <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
        <exclude-output />
        <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
          <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
        </content>
        <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
        <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
        <orderEntry type="library" name="scala " level="application" />
      </component>
    </module>
```

Notice that it does seem to be pointing to the correct jar compiler destination.

What do I need to do?

EDIT -

Compiler working now, but when I run, i get this error:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7540 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 10 CE.app/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/deploy.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javaws.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jce.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/management-agent.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/plugin.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/alt-rt.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/alt-string.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/charsets.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/classes.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/jsse.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/ui.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/apple_provider.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home:/Users/me/Projects/Scala/testing/out/test/testing:/Users/me/Projects/Scala/testing/out/production/testing:/Users/me/SDKs/scala/lib/scala-library.jar:/Users/me/SDKs/scala/lib/scala-swing.jar:/Users/me/SDKs/scala/lib/scala-dbc.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 10 CE.app/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain hello_world
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello_world
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I had same problems, just start new project and choose compiler accurately, as in answer with cool screenshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to project settings (that could be invoked by **Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S**) and choose *scala-compiler* in libraries list just like that:

[image]

Now `FacetManager` component looks like this:

```
<component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="scala" name="Scala">
      <configuration>
        <option name="compilerLibraryLevel" value="Global" />
        <option name="compilerLibraryName" value="scala-compiler-2.9.0.1" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't see the Scala compiler available. All I see is some scala lib that I created in libraries (I just attached a jar directory pointed to my scala SDK). How do I get the compiler to show up in there? Also, at this point intellij is complaining that multiple jars were found for the compiler. I'm guessing its because I'm pointing to the scala src folder which has multiple jars in it. I'm spinning my wheels here!

Comment: Wait, I think i fixed it! started a new project from scratch and manually pointed it to my scala dist. Apparently it wasn't finding it by itself before.

Comment: I can't seem to pick the correct run config that will just print to standard console output. I assumed I needed "scala console". But I'm getting errors with my configs: see above.

Answer (score 4):

See the [Project Configuration Guide](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/290032).

If you use SBT to build, I recommend using [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) to generate your IDEA project, and [idea-sbt-plugin](https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin/wiki) to delegate project compilation within IDEA to SBT.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to add the scala compiler library to the global libraries. In the module settings-> Global Libraries -> attach jar directories and select the lib folder under scala installation directory and then do as om-nom-nom suggested to make sure the compiler is selected.

Comment: Yep, you're completely right, _scala-compiler_ should be placed in the list of project libraries if it is not here before choosing it in file dialog and it could be added to list in that way.